# I need to find the distribution of days active within a week and Create a table to show how many members are active for each day

Tags: mysql, sql

For table Members:

```
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
| Field    | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
| S_Date   | date       | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| memberID | varchar(5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I need to find the distribution of days active within a week and Create a table to show how many members are active for 1 day, 2days, 3days,…7days during 3/1-3/7.

```
#Days Active    Count
1   
2   
3   
4   
5
```

I have tried bitwise operations and count operations but nothing works

Comment: Could you please add table structure, insert queries and expected output in your question , or create fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: +----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null   | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+-------+----+---------+-------+
| S_Date      | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| memberID | varchar(5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

Comment: Please red my comment before adding content to comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to count `Days Active` you can use `DATEDIFF` function to calculate the date diff days.then use `COUNT` and `group by` to get members are active.

I guess you can follow this query.

```
SET @StartDate := '2017-03-01';
SET @EndDate := '2017-03-07';

SELECT DATEDIFF(S_Date,@StartDate) + 1 'Days Active',
       COUNT(1) 'Count' 
FROM Members 
WHERE S_Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
GROUP BY S_Date
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa6ea3/1*

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you want a histogram-of-histogram query.  You would do this with two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT days_active, count(*) as num_members
FROM (SELECT memberID, COUNT(*) as days_active
      FROM Members 
      WHERE S_Date >= '2017-03-01' AND S_Date < '2017-03-07' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
      GROUP BY memberID
     ) m
GROUP BY days_active
ORDER BY days_active;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa6ea3/12) is the SQL Fiddle for this version.